# Calculus 1 - Intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I’ve been trying to solve the following question,it involves using the intermediate value theorem but I still have no clue on how to use it.Could anybody lend me a hand please?

Thank you in advance.

Assume that f : [0,1] → R is continuous and that 0 ≤ f(x) ≤ 1, for all x ∈ [0,1]. Prove that there exists c ∈ [0,1] such that f(c) = c.

Comment: I suggest you to explore website. I believe that you can find similar question

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser  Arthur, please accept my apologies on behalf of the site.  This site tends to be full of students, professors, etc on a Master's or PhD level.
I think for a Calculus I student, the continuous map question will be confusing.
A. intermediate value theorem is clearly a Calculus I concept.
B. Students in Calculus I are unlikely to be familiar with the following terms or ideas from your referenced question.  map, fixed point. 
Also, likely unfamiliar with the following- $\exists$ symbol, $\all$ symbol, proof by contradiction, and well defined function.